# Can an alternator maintain a good system voltage (14 volts measured at battery terminals) but not be supplying enough current?

Tags: electrical, alternator

I'm reading a car electronics textbook that claims that an alternator can maintain correct system voltage (say, 14 volts) when under load, yet not be outputting enough amperage. I can't understand how this is possible.
He claims that's why it's important to check the current output even if the voltage is good. Wouldn't it be necessarily putting out enough amps in order to maintain 14 volts?

Answer (score 1):

He is correct.

I tested alternators and sometimes one would have a phase down, so while it would show 14v, it would not output sufficient current.

This is why the correct testing procedures should be followed so that the “real” issue can be found.

Even following the posts on here, one can see that many have had a charging issue, jumped in and replaced the alternator as the voltage was low.. Then found they still have a problem and further testing shows a different issue... Sadly they paid for an alternator that was not needed.

So, do the correct tests.

Edit, you mention a textbook but don’t give any detail. However have a look at this link and it shows you a regulator circuit, older now, newer ones are even more complicated:

[enter link description here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=PaznCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA374&lpg=PA374&dq=16acr%20regulator%20circuit&source=bl&ots=JrL9k-QN8X&sig=ACfU3U0mZ4fYm2B16XJamGDyX43NvTB_8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj44I6Ktr_jAhW08aYKHcpNAHQQ6AEwHXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=16acr%20regulator%20circuit&f=false)

Comment: The book is "Automotive Electrical and Engine Performance" 8th edition by James Halderman. This is the quote on page 298:   "An alternator output test measures the current (amperes) of the alternator. A charging circuit may be able to produce correct charging circuit voltage, but not be able to produce adequate amperage." I am not disagreeing with him, I just don't quite understand how. The only way I can see how is if thr battery is fully charged (thus presenting a lower load) and the vehicle's electrical system is presenting a low load (all accessories off).

Comment: @brianfarrell re-read my answer, perhaps you need to test real alternators as that book does not seem to give adequate detail. As I said you only need one phase down or a diode pack problem. Did you figure out how the regulator works? The use of 3 transistors is classic and the zener diode ?

Comment: But, when we test voltage, we always load the system by turning on brights, radio, A/C, wipers, etc. In such a scenario, how could a defective alternator (not outputting enough current) maintain 14 volts? The regulator is complicated, but it's job is simple: to energize the rotor windings when it senses the voltage fall below the set value (say, 14 volts). The result of this is simply to put out more current. The process by which it does this is complicated, but the function is simple: cause more current to come from the alternator.

Comment: So you don’t know how the regulator works... When we studied this we had to produce that diagram from memory.

Comment: We have current supplied by the alternator, we have the load (which consists of the battery in parallel with the vehicle load) and we have a voltage (say, 14 volts). How does Ohms law not apply to this circuit? What is it about the regulator that allows Ohms law to be violated? The regulator may be complicated in how it works, but its function is simple to understand: it causes the alternator to output more current when voltage drops below a certain level and cause it to stop supplying current when voltage rises about the level.

Comment: And yes I actually do understand how that type of regulator works: the zener diode allows current to flow when its threshold voltage is reached and it becomes reverse biased. This turns on the first transistor which turns off the 2nd transistor causing the circuit of the rotor windings to be ungrounded. This causes the alternator to stop supplying current because the rotor no longer induces current in the stator. However, this has nothing to do with the circuit of the alternator supply to load and battery other than the sense voltage. It doesn't show why Ohms law may be violated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the veracity of your textbook.  There are some fundamental electrical laws that govern the current and voltage (and resistance).

Specifically Ohm's law:  voltage= resistance * amperage.

If the voltage readings are accurate, in order to create a 14 volt potential across the battery terminals, there *must* be a certain amount of current proportional to the resistance of the circuit.

The alternator doesn't "allocate" current based on a whim.  The current is a function of the difference in potential between battery voltage and alternator output voltage.  The current is a *result* proportional to that voltage delta and the resistance of the charging circuit.  The "hunger" of the battery ultimately determines the current, up to the capacity of the alternator.  If the alternator cannot keep up with the charging demand, it would not be able to generate a high voltage potential, unless there is some sort of high resistance in the charging circuit - which would not be a fault of the alternator itself.

Voltage regulation, either internal or external to the alternator, determines the alternator output in current to the battery up to the limit of the alternator capacity. If the regulator is working properly, it will not yield a voltage that puts a current demand on the alternator it cannot handle.

Comment: The regulator cannot keep up when someone boost starts a car with the engine running - and that can blow the alternator **even** if the regulator is working properly...

Comment: This was my thinking. Perhaps on a fully charged battery and very low load (just ignition and PCM), a faulty alternator would temporarily maintain 14 volts. But eventually the voltage would drop as the battery begins to lose charge. However, I can't mathematically conceptualize the scenario where 14 volts is showing at the battery terminals while under significant load (brights, A/C, radio) and yet the alternator is not supplying enough current, especially if the battery isn't 100% charged.

Comment: @SteveRacer How does the alternator or regulator get to see the battery "open circuit voltage"? The voltage the alternator or regulator sees is **always** due to the battery being in a circuit...

Comment: The regulator only knows if the voltage is dropping. If the battery is undercharged (lower open circuit voltage) it draws more current because it is providing less resistance. This causes the voltage to fall which causes the regulator to increase the current output of the alternator. My question is still: how can the alternator maintain voltage of 14 volts in a loaded circuit with a battery that may not be fully charged, and yet not be supplying enough current?

Comment: @brianfarrell well if you read my answer I gave you a reason...

Comment: @brianfarrell There are two things missing from your "why isn't 14V enough to charge the battery" idea. First, the alternator isn't there *only* to charge the battery. In fact, most of the time it is *not* charging the battery at all because it is fully charged already. It is supplying the power for everything else in the car (and that may be a lot, if all the lights are on, etc.). The battery only gets whatever output is "left over" after meeting that demand. The second issue is that a failing battery may need *more* than 14V to charge it *fast enough* to recover from starting the car.

Comment: In order to maintain a 14V drop across a total load (which includes the battery and the electrical demands of the vehicle connected in parallel) of R Ohms, the alternator must supply a current of 14/R amps. If it can't supply this much current, the voltage would drop. How then, could an alternator not supply enough current and still maintain a 14V drop across the load?

Comment: We're assuming that the battery isn't failing, lets assume a good battery with a state of charge of 80%. At 80% the resistance of the battery will be r, and the resistance of the electrical demands will be L. Then, in order to maintain 14V across the battery, the current output of the alternator must be 14(L+r)/Lr.  If its output is less than this, won't the voltage drop below 14V?  I'm not an electrical engineer, so I may be missing something. What am I missing?

Comment: @brianfarrell What you are missing is that you are applying simple Ohm’s law to a three-phase device with a complicated regulator control circuit. Add to that the alternator output is limited not infinite. Also the battery is not like a simple resistor in its behavior.

Comment: Why can't Ohms law be applied in this situation? Let's say 1 phase of the generator isn't working. Wouldn't that simply mean it's not generating enough current? Which would mean that the voltage would start to drop because of the load. The battery is acting like a resistor. It's resistance does depend on various factors: type, temperature, state of charge, state of health, size. etc. But it's still a load in parallel with the vehicle load and has a definite ohmic value.

Comment: The only way I can see how it can maintain 14 volts with a low output is if the battery is fully charged (thus a high resistance - low load) and the vehicle electrical system is presenting a low load (all accessories off). This all would obey ohms law. How can we ignore ohms law? What mathematical/circuit model can demonstrate a scenario where 14 volts is maintained under load with low current output. I want to understand it

Comment: @SolarMike  Nobody is applying Ohm's Law to a three-phase device.  I am talking about a good D+ wire, the voltage at B+, and the current flowing through D+.  Unless the battery has high resistance to charging (already fully charged (low V delta) or plate charge, or internal issues, there must be current to explain  the voltage drop between the DC alternator output and the battery voltage difference.  Perhaps there's an AC component that could fool a meter, but the true DC voltage at D+ *under load* mandates current flow.

Comment: Only a very high or infinite resistance to ground (e.g. broken or rotted D+ wire) would allow a scenario with 14 volts DC alternator "output" with little or no current flow.  D+ is a DC circuit (*or at least should be*) and will obey Ohm's Law.

Comment: @alephzero  I don't think that is what the OP was asking.  My read was he was asking "How can you have 14 volts DC at D+, with a low [than expected]  current flow?"  My test scenario is a fast DVOM on B+, and a clamp current meter around D+.  There is no scenario with *any* electrical load that can maintain 14 volts across the circuit with a current flow less than what is dictated by Ohm's Law.

Comment: Obviously Halderman is correct that one must run current and diode tests on the alternator, but I can't understand his comment that it could output "inadequate amperage but maintain correct charging voltage." Halderman is an expert in the automotive industry and he's written many textbooks. I don't think he's wrong, but I don't understand what he means.

Comment: @SteveRacer any alternator in goid condition that is not required to provide any current will hold the voltage at somewhere between 13.6 to 14.8 without issue ... And again as I put in my answer, having a phase down can also show the specified voltage whith a reduced current - especially with a diode pack fail. I have had these faults, tested and repaired the issues...

Comment: @SolarMike When you tested an alternator with a phase down, did it maintain good system voltage while under large load (i.e. battery not fully charged, brights, radio, a/c, wipers, etc)? If it did, then it must have been supplying a good deal of amperage despite having a phase down. Of course the current output and diodes must be tested. I'm not arguing that point. I'm just questioning the idea that it can output inadequate current under load while maintaining 14 volts.

Comment: @brianfarrell get yourself an alternator and cause a phase to be down and then conduct the tests yourself. I have other things to do - I gave you an answer, which you have not even recognised with a point lety alone accepted.

Comment: I guess I could have destroyed an alternator and hooked it up to a car and run all kinds of tests, but instead I decided to ask a question on this forum. Your answer seems to be that, yes, an alternator can be outputting low current yet still maintaining a good system voltage while under a heavy load. Is thst correct? If so, my real question is: how does this not violate Ohms law? And if we can violate it in this scenario, how does this work mathematically? What circuit diagram can demonstrate how a low current output can maintain approx 14 volts under load?

Comment: What *is* possible is that the alternator is putting out low DC current, but is perhaps putting out a high ripple voltage and current (AC) that the kind of meters Halderman uses may not be quick enough to show the issue on a DC setting.  I used this exact same book when I taught for several years, and I reviewed several chapters for Prentice Hall on later editions.  I love Halderman's work, but sometimes he phrases things a bit loosely.   You'll notice that immediately following that quoted line, the sections on "AC" ripple voltage and current testing are described.

Comment: This may be a bit of semantics, much of which I will accept the blame for.  While I maintain it is impossible for a DC circuit to not obey Ohm's law, I will say if there is excess ripple on D+, this is no longer a DC circuit, and the *observed* DC current my not be the *true* DC current and/or the instrument used is insufficient to capture the real picture.

Comment: @SolarMike  Sound reasonable to you?

Comment: @SteveRacer This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your explanation. I like Halderman as well and have learned a lot from his books.